# How to effectively find all PDF's on disk and copy to one folder?

Tags: command-line, find

I have a removable disk via usb connected to my laptop with Ubuntu.

I want to find all PDF's on that additional disk and copy them all to a folder in my home directory. Is there a quick and easy way of doing this, preferably a chain of commandline commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/find.1.html):

```
find /path/to/disk -iname '*.pdf' -type f -exec cp --no-clobber --target-directory ~/target/folder {}  +
```

- `-iname '*.pdf'` matches files ending in PDF (case-insensitive)
- `-type f` matches only regular files (so a directory with name ending in `.pdf` wouldn't be copied)
- `-exec` runs commands with `{}` substituted with the name of matching file. With `+`, it will run a single command with names of many matching files.
- We use `-exec` to run `cp --target-directory ~/target/folder`. Explicitly specifying the target directory (and `--no-clobber`) should safeguard against an accidental typo overwriting files.

Comment: nice code organisation dude. i mean nice use of options. your code does not have any loop hole

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Pretty sure someone on [unix.se] can poke holes in it. But can never be too careful while copying.

Comment: @muru looks briliant, I'm just starting to use linux (Ubuntu) more so I'm a newie. Hope you don't mind me asking. There is no chance that some files will get ommited, right?

Comment: @so_user There is, if they have the same name as a file already copied (to avoid overwriting).

Comment: @so_user As a workaround, you can run the command once with `mv` instead of `cp` to move the files, then a second time with a different target directory (so that files that were not copied due to name clashes are then copied).

Comment: You could also consider using the `--backup` option e.g. `--backup=numbered` to give unique suffixes to any conflicting files.

Comment: FWIW the only holes I could see the U&L nitpickers pouncing on are (1) terminating `cp`'s optional parameter list with `--` to handle the rare case of filenames starting with a hyphen; and (2) there are supposedly some advantages in using `-execdir` in place of `-exec`.

Comment: @steeldriver I forgot about the backup option. Thanks. And using `-execdir` will actually negate the need for `--`, since the advantage is that the filenames have `./` prefixed. :)

Comment: @muru doh! I was forgetting about the path prefix - you're right of course